# extract value from string using php

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to extract the start date `April 1, 2017` using `preg_match_all()` from the following line where Both date is dynamic.

```
for April 1, 2017 to April 30, 2017

$contents = "for April 1, 2017 to April 30, 2017";
if(preg_match_all('/for\s(.*)+\s(.*)+,\s(.*?)+ to\s[A-Za-z]+\s[1-9]+,\s[0-9]\s/', $contents, $matches)){
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Comment: You may use something like `preg_match_all('~\b[a-z]+\s*\d{1,2},\s*\d{4}\b~i', $contents, $matches)`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yzpGr8/2).

Comment: Or perhaps match the whole string with 2 capturing groups `\bfor\h+(\w+\h+\d{1,2},\h+\d{4})\h+to\h+((?1))\b` https://regex101.com/r/LCvlqW/1

Comment: It's working but you can elaborate in details in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match the whole string and match the 2 date like patterns you could use 2 capturing groups.

Note that it does not validate the date itself.

```
\bfor\h+(\w+\h+\d{1,2},\h+\d{4})\h+to\h+((?1))\b
```

In parts

- `\bfor\h+` Word boundary, match `for` and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w+\h+\d{1,2}` Match 1+ word chars, 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and 1 or 2 digits
  - `,\h+\d{4}` Match a comma, 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and 4 digits
- `)` Close group
- `\h+to\h+` Match `to` between 1+ horizontal whitspace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?1)` [Subroutine call](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines) to capture group 1  (the same pattern of group 1 as it is the same logic)
- `)` Close group
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZrINf2/1)

For example

```
$re = '/\bfor\h+(\w+\h+\d{1,2},\h+\d{4})\h+to\h+((?1))\b/';
$str = 'for April 1, 2017 to April 30, 2017';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches)
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => for April 1, 2017 to April 30, 2017
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => April 1, 2017
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => April 30, 2017
        )

)
```